# elasticsearch search by one letter

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index which is set like this:

```
settings: {
index.analysis.analyzer.eng_search_analyzer.filter.0: lowercase
index.analysis.analyzer.eng_search_analyzer.filter.1: icu_folding
index.analysis.analyzer.eng_search_analyzer.char_filter.0: html_strip
index.analysis.filter.eng_ngram_filter.type: nGram
index.analysis.filter.eng_ngram_filter.min_gram: 1
index.analysis.analyzer.eng_search_analyzer.tokenizer: whitespace
index.analysis.analyzer.eng_search_analyzer.filter.2: icu_normalizer
index.analysis.analyzer.eng_index_analyzer.filter.1: eng_ngram_filter
index.analysis.analyzer.eng_index_analyzer.filter.0: lowercase
index.number_of_shards: 2
index.analysis.filter.eng_ngram_filter.token_chars.1: digit
index.analysis.filter.eng_ngram_filter.token_chars.0: letter
index.analysis.filter.eng_ngram_filter.token_chars.3: symbol
index.analysis.filter.eng_ngram_filter.token_chars.2: punctuation
index.analysis.analyzer.eng_index_analyzer.type: custom
index.analysis.analyzer.eng_index_analyzer.char_filter.0: html_strip
index.analysis.analyzer.eng_index_analyzer.filter.3: icu_normalizer
index.analysis.filter.eng_ngram_filter.max_gram: 20
index.analysis.analyzer.eng_index_analyzer.filter.2: icu_folding
index.number_of_replicas: 1
index.analysis.analyzer.eng_index_analyzer.tokenizer: whitespace
index.analysis.analyzer.eng_search_analyzer.type: custom
index.version.created: 900799
index.uuid: -O-iV6ZIQh6gk1204Ec1ig
}
```

And the field mapping of several important fields is set like this:

```
{
  "name": {
    "type": "multi_field",
    "fields": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "omit_norms": "true",
        "index_options": "docs",
        "null_value": ""
      },
      "analyzed": {
        "type": "string",
        "index_analyzer": "eng_index_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "eng_search_analyzer",
        "null_value": "",
        "include_in_all": "false"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I query the name.analyzed field, it works fine for anything with at least two characters. For examples, querying "Ra" will find documents with "Rafael" in the name field. However, when I query "R" or "Rafael S", it doesn't return any result. It should be noted that in our query, whitespaces are handled as "AND" operator and not as "OR", so basically the query term is handled like - "name contains [search term]".

How can I configure the field or the analyzer so that searching for single-letters will work?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say withouth seeing the query, but according to a [discussion on the elastic forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/single-letter-term-matches-cause-noise-in-search-results/45698/2) if you're using a [match_phrase_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) query, you may have some success by increasing the "max_expansions" property for the query, though it will decrease the speed.

`"max_expansions": 10000`

Anther potential solution in that thread is to set `operator` or `default_operator` to `"and"` (which I think you've done).